# HTML encoding in username tooltip on stackexchange.com/sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, tooltips, html-entities

On https://stackexchange.com/sites, when you click on a site's bubble, you can see the top five users on that site. When you hover over the profile picture, you can see the name and the rep of the user. The problem is, if the user has apostrophes in his name, the tooltip shows up with `&#39;` instead of `'`.

[image: tooltip]

His username is [d'alar'cop](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2484/dalarcop), not `d&#39;alar&#39;cop`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed, thanks. The data is cached fairly heavily, so depending on which server you hit, it may take a moment (up to 24 hours, but probably less) until you see the difference.

Comment: I just noticed this happens in the tooltip on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/45128/puzzling) too, like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bAl3u.png).

Comment: @mmking Thanks for the pointer, should be fixed soon-ish.